# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException new1.EmployeeController.findByUsername()

Tags: grails, groovy

I was trying to make a signup page, which takes the username and password as from the user and stores it in my database, but the problem here is, the data is not going to the database only

you can see the image here

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9gjSzsLSnClR1VvU0RUa3liRWs/view?usp=sharing][1]

> save method look likes this

```
@Transactional
def save(){
    if(params == null){
        redirect(action:"index")
        flash.message=''
        return
    }
    def employee = findByUsername(params.username);
    System.out.println(employee.username);  
    if(employee!=null){
        flash.message="username already exist"
        render(view:"signup")
    }
    else{
        def newEmp = new Employee();
        newEmp.username=params.username
        newEmp.password=params.password
        if(newEmp.save(flush:true)){
            flash.message="Employee created"
            render(view:"index")
        }
        else{
            flash.message="Please enter valid data"
            render(view:"signup")
        }
        if(newEmp.save(flush:true)) {
            flash.message = "User Created. Please Login"
            render(view:"index") 
        } else {            
            flash.message = "Please enter valid data";
            render(view:"signup") 
        } 
    }
}
```

> View page look like this

```
<form id="signupform" action="./save" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" role="form">                
                    <g:if test="${flash.message}">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">${flash.message}</div> 
                    </g:if>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username" class="col-md-3 control-label">Username</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password" class="col-md-3 control-label">Password</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <!-- Button -->                                        
                        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9 text-center">
                            <button id="btn-signup" type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-hand-right"></i>Sign Up</button> 
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
def employee = findByUsername(params.username);
```

with:

```
def employee = Employee.findByUsername(params.username);
```

All dynamic finder methods must be called statically on the type you expect them to return